# Why I am getting 400 error on https://www.googleapis.com/appsactivity/v1/activities?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I am always getting 400 - Bad request - invalidArgument

```
400 OK


- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  133
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Tue, 07 Apr 2015 11:11:32 GMT
expires:  Tue, 07 Apr 2015 11:11:32 GMT
server:  GSE
vary:  Origin, X-Origin

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

I am not using any parameter, in the documentation their all are optional

this error comes in all the below cases

1. Documentation page demo
2. playground
3. using python api

Can somebody help me?, what I am doing wrong? you can try in the documentation page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/reference/activities/list?hl=es

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Ok I found the issue,

the **source** and **drive.fileId** are not optional, is an error in the documentation, source should be ="drive.google.com"  and drive.fileId="file_id"

@dubhov, thank for the help. but "YOUR_API_KEY" is handle internally by google.

Comment: Your response to @dubhov should be a comment on their answer, not in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The page demo works,

you need to send only one drive.fileId or drive.ancestorId, if you use both it will return "invalidArgument".

source should be = drive.google.com

And authorize requests using OAuth 2.0.

This is all you need to make it work.

good luck.